# How to migrate an SVG graphics into a gliffy graphics not as embedded picture

Tags: svg, confluence, inkscape, gliffy

In my current project I generated a bunch of SVG graphics from an Enterprise Architect model.

Now, the customer wants to edit these graphics right in the tool Gliffy, being an addon in Confluence.

Up to now, I'm just successful to add the SVG graphics as an embedded SVG image into Gliffy. This has the serious drawback, that no edits of shapes/lines are possible. How can I really migrate an SVG graphics to Gliffy. I really want to avoid to redraw all the SVG graphics in Gliffy itself.

Comment: gliffy can import visio drawings and visio can import svg

Comment: @RobertLongson: Just tried to import an arbitrary example visio drawing in gliffy, but I failed. Is there a special submenu or an extension for Gliffy necessary to do so?

Comment: https://help.gliffy.com/confluence/Content/GliffyConfluence/Importing-diagrams-Confluence.htm